# RDF/OWL to TRIPLE store

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl, protege

I have created an ontology in Protege. Now for my application to have better scalability I like to convert the OWL file to triple store and query the store.

How to convert owl file to triple store?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, OWL is not RDF. [The specification of OWL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/) defines ontologies as a radically different structure than sets of triples. However, all [OWL ontologies can be written as RDF graphs](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/), so you can directly store them in a triple store, without any preprocessing (note that any conformant OWL tool [MUST be able to serialise ontologies in RDF/XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-owl2-conformance-20091027/#Document_Conformance)).

Answer (score 1):

owl is also RDF , and you can use jena to load it into TDB

Answer (score 1):

You can try [OWLIM](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim) and [Stardog](http://stardog.com). Both are triple store solutions for OWL ontologies.